# Why key is null?, despite I created it

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, key

I created a list based in an array using a custom component, and it works, but not properly, because I did try to send a 'key' prop in the component implementation, but inside the component, key prop doesn't exist, is just undefined.

The expected behaviour is to access to the 'key' prop inside the component, and avoid the "key is not a prop" warning on my app.

This is the data

```
            data: [
                { key: 1, definition: "Def 1", example: "Example text 1" },
                { key: 2, definition: "Def 2", example: "Example text 2" },
                { key: 3, definition: "Def 3", example: "Example text 3" }
            ]
```

This is the component implementation

```
createDefinitions = (data) => {
    return data.map((item, index) => {
        return <Definition {...item}/>
    })
}
```

'item' is an object with every duple in the previous array. Actually, I tried to add 'key' prop directly in this point, but it was the same.

Inside the custom component I tried to print the props object, but 'key' doesn't exist

```
<Text>{JSON.stringify(props)}</Text>
```

You can the code here https://snack.expo.io/r1VE3DiQV

The expected behaviour is to get key property inside custom component.

Thanks!

Comment: The code youve posted isn't the same as what you have here and looks like it would work, you need to use this.props or this.state depending on whether you want to access the state passed down as props, some other props or the local state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** you cannot access a `key` via `this.props.key`. If you need the value that you set for the `key` pass it via a different name such as `id`.

---

You cannot access the key property via props once you have set it. If you try to access it you will get the following yellow warning

[image: yellow box warning for accessing key prop]

> Warning: %s: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in
>   `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value
>   within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.
>   https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html

*I've used the actual url that the link resolves to as SO complains about the use of shortened urls*

Following the link in the warning gives you the following message:

> Most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, however,
>   there are two special props (**ref** and **key**) which are used by React, and
>   are thus not forwarded to the component.

It then goes on to tell you that if you require access to the value you should set it as a different prop.

> For instance, attempting to access this.props.key from a component
>   (i.e., the render function or propTypes) is not defined. If you need
>   to access the same value within the child component, you should pass
>   it as a different prop (ex: 
>   `<ListItemWrapper key={result.id} id={result.id} />`). While this may seem redundant, it’s important to
>   separate app logic from reconciling hints.

Looking at your code it, is working fine, the only issue is that you are trying to access the key which isn't passed via props. If you remove the references to `props.key` in your `Definition` component the warning should go.

Comment: Using the key 'key' was my error, now is working pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list of elements by mapping over your data, and in that case you need to add a `key` prop (with a string value) to each list element. This is completely unrelated to the data object you are using, but you could use that key as prop value. So in this case you need to add a `key` prop to Definition:

```
createDefinitions = (data) => {
  return data.map((item, index) => {
    return <Definition key={item.key.toString()} {...item}/>
  })
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use the index if you don't have unique keys in your data

Comment: Is the same if you make the cast to string, but thanks for help :)